# How to navigate outside of components in ReactRouter 4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In React Router (v3) I can accept a server response and use browserHistory.push to go to the appropriate response page. However, this isn't available in v4, and I'm not sure what the appropriate way to handle this is in React-Router V4 .

In below example when the server returns a success, the user is taken to the Cart page

// actions/index.js

```
export function addProduct(props) {
  return dispatch =>
    axios.post(`${ROOT_URL}/cart`, props, config)
      .then(response => {
        dispatch({ type: types.AUTH_USER });
        localStorage.setItem('token', response.data.token);
        browserHistory.push('/cart'); // no longer in React Router V4
      });
}
```

How can I make a redirect to the page from function in React Router v4?

I can find lot of references on navigation from components in my case i need to navigate from a function

Answer (score -2):

If you want program router to somewhere, use **history** is the best solutions, Them problem here is how to get the **history** object in component:

- **Route**: render component with **Route**
- **WithRouter**: wrap component:

  class yourcomponent extends Component {}

  withRouter()(yourcomponent)

If you want do this in **Redux**, then you could try with **React-Router-Redux**